# BigQuery Pagination through large result set with cloud library

Tags: java, pagination, google-bigquery

I am working on accessing data from Google BigQuery, the data is 500MB which I need to transform as part of the requirement. I am setting `Allow Large Results`, setting a `destination table` etc.

I have written a java job in Google's new cloud library since that is recommended now - `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:0.21.1-beta` (I have tried 0.20 beta as well without any fruitful results)

I am having problem with pagination of this data, the library is inconsistent in fetching results page wise. Here is my code snippet,

### Code Snippet

```
    System.out.println("Accessing Handle of Response");
    QueryResponse response = bigquery.getQueryResults(jobId, QueryResultsOption.pageSize(10000));
    System.out.println("Got Handle of Response");

    System.out.println("Accessing results");
    QueryResult result = response.getResult();
    System.out.println("Got handle of Result. Total Rows: "+result.getTotalRows());

    System.out.println("Reading the results");
    int pageIndex = 0;
    int rowId = 0;
    while (result != null) {
        System.out.println("Reading Page: "+ pageIndex);
        if(result.hasNextPage())
        {
            System.out.println("There is Next Page");       
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No Next Page");
        }

        for (List<FieldValue> row : result.iterateAll()) {
            System.out.println("Row: " + rowId);
            rowId++;
        }

        System.out.println("Getting Next Page: ");
        pageIndex++;
        result = result.getNextPage();
    }
```

### Output print statements

```
Accessing Handle of Response  
Got Handle of Response  
Accessing results  
Got handle of Result. Total Rows: 9617008  
Reading the results  
Reading Page: 0  
There is Next Page  
Row: 0  
Row: 1  
Row: 2  
Row: 3  
:  
:  
Row: 9999  
Row: 10000  
Row: 10001  
:  
:  
Row: 19999  
:  
:
```

Please note that it never hits/prints - "Getting Next Page: ".

My expectation was that I would get data in chunks of 10000 rows at a time. Please note that if I run the same code on a query which returns 10-15K rows and set the pageSize to be 100 records, I do get the "Getting Next Page:" after every 100 rows. Is this a known issue with this beta library?

Answer (score 0):

This looks very close to a problem I have been struggling with for hours. And I just found the solution, so I will share it here, even though you probably found a solution yourself a long time ago.

I did exactly like the documentation and tutorials said, but my page size were not respected and I kept getting all rows every time, no matter what I did. Eventually I found another example, official I think, [right here](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquery/blob/main/samples/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/bigquery/QueryPagination.java).

What I learned from that example is that you should only use `iterateAll()` to get the rest of the rows. To get the current page rows you need to use `getValues()` instead.